# How do you make an object solid so that it doesn't become overlapped by hover items? (CSS & HTML)

Tags: html, css, hover, geometry, overlapping

Im creating a website for a Software Design project and one of the criteria is that nothing is allowed to overlap. I have a hover feature so that when you hover over the steps, the process of the step is shown.

With step 2 & 3 the text displayed during the hover effect is blocked by the edge of the webpage so it makes new lines in a kind of paragraph form.

Screenshot of Webpage with hover effect on step 2:
http://s32.postimg.org/kw0u3lk8l/Screen_Shot_2016_05_14_at_7_05_13_PM.png

This is what I want to do with step 7 & 8 as instead of being blocked by anything they continue as a string, overlapping the circle. So i was wondering if there was a way of making the circle a solid object or something that cannot be overlapped, forcing the text to make new lines.

Image of the overlap on step 8 hover effect below:
http://s32.postimg.org/yof8z8b05/Screen_Shot_2016_05_14_at_7_05_25_PM.png

Here is my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fetch Execute Cycle</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
           box-sizing: border-box;
           background-color: #faa635;
        }
        *, *:before, *:after {
           box-sizing: inherit;
        }
        body {
            font: 16px/1.5 "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
            margin: 1em;
        }
        h1 {
            font-family: American Captain, "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
        }
        .circle {
            width:450px;
            height:450px;
            border-radius:50%;
            border: solid;
            color:#3658bf;
            line-height:500px;
            background:#000;
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        .centered {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        /* COMMON HOVER EFFECTS */
        .common {
            display: block;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-align: center;
            border: 2px solid #3658bf;
            color: #3658bf;
            background: transparent;
            border-radius: .25rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: .5rem;
            position: absolute;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .common:hover {
            background: rgba(54, 88, 191, 0.888);
            color: #fff;
        }
        .common:focus {
            outline: 0;
        }
        .common:hover {
            font-size: 0;
        }
        .common:hover:after {
            content: attr(data-hover);
            font-size: 1rem;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        /* HELP */
        .help {
            left: 50%;
            top: 13%;
        }

        /* STEP 1 */
        .step1 {
            left: 70%;
            top: 20%;
        }

        /* STEP 2 */
        .step2 {
            left: 80%;
            top: 40%;
        }

        /* STEP 3 */
        .step3 {
            left: 80%;
            top: 65%;
        }

        /* STEP 4 */
        .step4 {
            left: 70%;
            top: 82%;
        }

        /* STEP 5 */
        .step5 {
            left: 50%;
            top: 90%;
        }

        /* STEP 6 */
        .step6 {
            left: 30%;
            top: 82%;
        }

        /* STEP 7 */
        .step7 {
            left: 20%;
            top: 65%;
        }

        /* STEP 8 */
        .step8 {
            left: 20%;
            top: 40%;
        }

        /* STEP 9 */
        .step9 {
            left: 30%;
            top: 20%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><center><u>[]'s example of the Fetch Execute Cycle</u>    </center></h1>
    <div class="circle"><img class ="centered" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/4tsk5i.png" onMouseOver="this.src='https://i.imgsafe.org/67289f5.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='http://i64.tinypic.com/4tsk5i.png'" border="0" alt="Fetch Execute Cycle Image" width="300"></div>

    <!-- Help -->
    <a class="common help" data-hover="Hover over steps for information">Help</a>

    <!-- Step 1 -->
    <a class="common step1" data-hover="Fetching the instruction from primary storage!">Step 1</a>

    <!-- Step 2 -->
    <a class="common step2" data-hover="Decoding the instruction into an operation code and data addresses!">Step 2</a>

    <!-- Step 3 -->
    <a class="common step3" data-hover="Copying the operation code into the instruction register!">Step 3</a>

    <!-- Step 4 -->
    <a class="common step4" data-hover="Copying the addresses of the data into the address register!">Step 4</a>

    <!-- Step 5 -->
    <a class="common step5" data-hover="Using the address register to copy the data into the storage register!">Step 5</a>

    <!-- Step 6 -->
    <a class="common step6" data-hover="Sending the operation code and data to the ALU!">Step 6</a>

    <!-- Step 7 -->
    <a class="common step7" data-hover="Executing the instruction on the data!">Step 7</a>

    <!-- Step 8 -->
    <a class="common step8" data-hover="Sending the result to the accumulator, ready for the next instruction!">Step 8</a>

    <!-- Step 9 -->
    <a class="common step9" data-hover="Storing the results in primary storage!">Step 9</a>

</body>
```

Comment: Found the solution to my problem. It is featured below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue a width must be specified, then you can word-wrap. 
So add the lines into css for .common:

```
width:250px;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Duh...? You want to enforce a width, how else would you do it?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Idk, thats why I asked the question.